# how to associate two models using has_many and belongs_to ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, model-associations, belongs-to

I have generated two models tour and tourcategories in my application. Now I want to associate these two models using `has_many` and `belongs_to`. Where tour can relate with single tourcategory but tourcategory can have more than one tours. So definition of the `tour` model is following:

```
class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tourcategory
  attr_accessible :content, :element_id, :job_id, :title, :priority, :tourcategory
end
```

this is the definition of tourcategory model:

```
class Tourcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tours
  attr_accessible :title
end
```

this is the definition of the tours migration file:
class `CreateTours < ActiveRecord::Migration`

```
def change
    create_table :tours do |t|
      t.string :element_id
      t.string :title
      t.text :content
      t.integer :job_id
      t.integer :priority
      t.belongs_to :tourcategory, index:true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

this is the definition of the tours controller :

```
def new
        @tourcategories = Tourcategory.all
        @tour = Tour.new
        @tour.build_tour
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @tour }
        end
    end
```

Now I am getting an error

```
undefined method `tourcategories'
```

When I access the `_form.html.haml` view  for editing and for adding new tour.
this the code where error is encountered.

```
.field
    = label_tag "tour Categories"
    %br/
    = select_tag "tourcategory", options_from_collection_for_select(Tourcategory.all, 'id', 'title', @tour.tourcategories.map{ |j| j.id })
    = f.submit
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You actually need to use HABTM (Has And Belongs To Many) - please check out [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You defined,
Tourcategory has multiple tours. `has_many :tours`
Tour belongs to one Tourcategory. `belongs_to :tourcategory`

So, you can not call `tourcategories` from `@tour`. you can call `tourcategory` from `@tour`

Additionaly,
`@tour.build_tour` <- makes error maybe.
you can use `build_*` method for `belongs_to` relation.
I think you should try `@tour.build_tourcategory`

Read "Action Record Association" section in Rails Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `@tour.tourcategories`, because a `Tour` belongs to a single `Tourcategory`, so that method wouldn't be generated by Rails. You may call `@tour.tourcategory` or `@tourcategory.tours`.

Why are you passing a fourth argument to `options_for_collection_from_select` anyway? That `map` method will return a collection, but you want an element. Try omitting it and see if it works.

A couple more issues with your code:

`@tour.build_tour` won't work unless you have explicitly defined that method (and if you have, it might be better to name it something else). All `build_something` methods are generated for `has_one` relationships. Maybe you're looking for `@tourcategory.tours.build`.

You shouldn't call `Tourcategory.all` from your view, instead use the `@tourcategories` variable you defined in the controller. Views should never call models directly.

If you're using Rails 4, you shouldn't be using `attr_accessible`, but rather define strong parameters in the controller.

Hope that helps.